# Excel Macro Find Text value Cut and Paste then shift cells up

Tags: excel, paste, shift

I have a nightmare task to migrate from one accounting package to another.

I have 9340 rows in columns A,B and G which needs to be ordered in a certain way before it can be imported by new system.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

I ran a macro that does what I want but only for selected range. How do I make macro work for entire sheet?

```
Sub Macro1()

  Range("B206").Select
  Selection.Cut
  Range("A207").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Rows("206:206").Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  Range("A206").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("A206:A216").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Range("C216").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.Cut
  Range("G216").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us more about how the data is currently ordered and how you want it to be ordered when you're done.

Comment: Before :[IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/2daccqs.png[/IMG]

Comment: After:[IMG]http://i50.tinypic.com/8x77zt.png[/IMG]

Comment: Thanks for your response Doug. I had to use the images as it is hard to explain

Comment: Are there empty rows between different accounts?

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks again. Nope there are no empty rows between diff accounts but when moving the persons name to the left of the opening balance creates the empty row. (I guess the new database program needs the persons name next to opening balance and transactions to associate it when importing data)

Answer (score 0):

This will likely fail in some respect. Your setup is more complicated than I have time to re-create. Please run this code on a **copy** of your data. It basically moves things around and then deletes all the rows that have blanks in column B. You should delete the header junk above the first "Opening" row:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In .Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    If Left(cell.Value, Len("Opening")) = "Opening" Then
        cell.Offset(1, -1).Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Offset(-1, -1).Value
    End If
    If Left(cell.Value, Len("Closing")) = "Closing" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    End If
Next cell
    .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help Doug, unfortunately I had to sort the sheet manually as time was not on my side. I deleted the header junk and had opening balance at row 1 then ran code and got error cell.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Offset(-1, -1).Value. thanks for everything